# jQuery how to build json object from html tag attributes

Tags: jquery, json

I have a table and on each row I add some attributes that later I need to get when I click on the row with `jQuery`.

Here is a sample of a `<tr>` element:

```
<tr data-id="1" data-employeeid="4" data-acceess="none" data-area="HR">
   <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">ID 01</td>
   <td>This is a custom descriptiion</td>                                                   
</tr>
```

I would like to build a `json` object based on `data.*` attributes but also adding the column values.

So in this example I would like to get something like this:

```
{'employeeid':'4', 'access':'none', 'area':'HR', 'data1':'ID 01', 'data2':'This is a custom description'}
```

> Any clue?

Comment: That's completely invalid, it should be `data-access` etc.

Comment: @adeneo what do you mean? appreciate your feedback

Comment: You shouldn't have attributes with periods in them, and you should be using data-attributes, as in a hyphen

Comment: Great feedback let me change that in my code and in the question here...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use valid data attributes

```
<tr data-id="1" data-employeeid="4" data-acceess="none" data-area="HR">
```

All you need is `$(element).data()` to get all of them as an object.
If you wanted to add the text from all the children elements as well, you could extend that object

```js
var tr   = $('tr[data-id="1"]');
var data = tr.data();

$.extend(data, $('td',tr).toArray().reduce(function(a,b,i) {
 a['data' + (i+1)] = $(b).text();
    return a;
}, {}));

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr data-id="1" data-employeeid="4" data-acceess="none" data-area="HR">
        <td class="sorting_1" tabindex="0">ID 01</td>
        <td>This is a custom descriptiion</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```